# What's the difference between a tuple and a compressed_pair?

Tags: c++, boost, tuples

I've seen both used for the same purpose, but I wonder how the result would differ (if at all) and why this is used at all.

References to docs: [`compressed_pair`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/compressed_pair.htm) and [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: std::pair is a tuple of two elements. Tuples can be any number of elements(of any type). I'd imagine the docs on compressed_pair can explain anything else. (But I'd assume it makes several storage-relevant optimizations)

Comment: @GRAYgoose124: Just the one, the _empty base optimization_.

Comment: Well, wouldn't a tuple already provide the necessary "compression", even for two elements?

Comment: @rubenvb No. `compressed_pair`'s 'compression' is really just the [empty base class optimization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization)

Comment: @rubenvb A `tuple` *could* provide EBO to reduce size, but it's not required to.

Comment: @K-ballo: Uhm... *one is a pair the other is a tuple* correct. *One is compressed the other isn't*, not so much. Tuples are *compressed* AFAIK

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Tuples **may** be compressed, but they don't have to be. You cannot count on it.

Comment: And since C++20, it can be done with [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

C++ requires all [complete types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) to have a size greater than 0.  If a type *could* have a size of 0, array indexing and other pointer math would go awry.

```
class EmptyClass { };

std::cout << sizeof( EmptyClass );  // Prints "1" (typically)
```

A `boost::compressed_pair` is a tuple of two elements doesn't require additional storage for one type that only has a size of 1 because a size of 0 is forbidden.

```
if ( sizeof( compressed_pair<int,EmptyClass> ) == sizeof(int) )
{
   std::cout << "EmptyClass was compressed.";  // (This will print)
}
```

This is achieved through [Empty Base Optimization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization).  Both types are put in a class wrapper, and if one type is "empty", that class becomes the parent of the other.

Comment: Why are you taking the size of the `compressed_pair` class. Doesn't it return a type through which you can access with `::[name_of_type]`?…

Comment: @0x499602D2 (Unless I'm confused) it illustrates that the presence of `EmptyClass` does not add to the size of the `compressed_pair` as a whole.

Comment: How could the size of `compressed_pair` be the same size as `int` I'm basically trying to say.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh - it does it by putting each type in a wrapper class and having the `int` wrapper inherit from the `EmptyClass` wrapper in this case.  See this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization

Comment: You can also achieve the same optimization through `[[no_unique_address]]` starting from C++20. (Visual Studio uses an extension instead `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]`. See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/))